# How to open a react native app through a web page link

Tags: ios, react-native

I am currently working on an iOS app built with React Native and am trying to create a web page that links to the app.

I have gotten it to work on a page served from my test server on a different domain. i.e. I can open a page on testserver.com/index.html in the browser, and tapping a link to productionserver.com/some/page DOES open the app.

However, when attempting the same on a page served from the production domain, (a page served by productionserver.com), the app does not open, and instead the browser attempts to navigate to the URL of the linked page. The same happens in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Since I can link to the app from testserver.com I am sure that the app is correctly configured, but I suspect the problem has something to do with the domain serving the page and the domain of the app link being the same.

I have tried using a universal link by adding an apple-app-site-association file in the web server root directory with the following contents:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "abc123.com.myapp.app",
                "paths": [ "/some/page", "/another/page" ]
            },
            {
                "appID": "abc123.com.myapp.test",
                "paths": [ "/some/page", "/another/page" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: host file at .well-known/ instead of root

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Xhirazi. I just tried this but the behavior is the same.